# Import data from Excel 2010 into datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, excel-2010

I want to import data from Excel 2010 in to datagridview using this code but doesn't show any result? What should I do?

```
 private void btn_calHazine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            // String name = "Items";
            String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                    @"C:\Users\Mohsen\Desktop\Book1.xlsx" +
                    ";Extended Properties='Excel 14.0;HDR=YES;';";

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [ Sheet1$]", con);
            con.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dgv_sabadkharid.DataSource = data;

        }
        catch { }
}
```

Comment: You get any exception or error message?

Comment: I get an exception the Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB provider is not registered on the local machine. I use Microsoft excel 2010

Comment: exception Ocured : Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB provider is not Registered on Local Machine.